# Sharepoint: Setting url in onet.xml NavBar

Tags: sharepoint

I have the following NavBar element in my onet.xml. It adds the link "Link" to the quicklauch bar, but seems to ignore the body attribute. I'm particularly interested in setting the href to what I want (/Lists/Link/AllItems.aspx), but it doesn't work.
Any help?

I'm working on Moss 2007.

```
<NavBar Name="Link"
    Prefix="&lt;table border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0&gt;"
    Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif'
    ID='100' alt='' border=0&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign=top&gt;&lt;a ID=onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID# href='/Lists/Link/AllItems.aspx'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;"
    Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1033" />
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the URL is relative to the root site, so try using the site context with:

```
 Url="_layouts/[%=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.
      CurrentUICulture.LCID%]/yourpage.aspx"
```

Hope this may help.